# What is the order of decreasing stability among following molecules?

Tags: aromatic-compounds, resonance

[image]

I am almost certain that (IV) is most stable and (III) is least stable. How to compare between (I) and (II)? Is it something related to angle strain?

I am also confused if you can compare between compounds having different amounts of carbon molecules. (I) and (II) have 7 carbon molecules so they would have more bond energy. Is it possible that (I) and (II) could be more stable than (IV) because of this reason?

Comment: You are right, it is a flawed question. For a direct comparison, you need molecules with the same molecular formula like I and II.

Comment: @KarstenTheis Thanks! How to compare between I and II?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/31808/72973

Comment: Is the answer option c?